# How to train model in Colab with no effect of interruption to the internet?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am working on training some deep learning mode. It takes several hours to train such model in Google Colaboratory. I need to remain online full hours to train the model successively. Is there any solution to make Google colab train the model and if any internet interruption occurs, make no hamper to the training. Otherwise I need to train from the start.

Comment: as I know, even when you close the browser, Colab will run the last cell till it finish. So try to save checkpoints or save the model right after training